# Automatically log the user out when the browser or tab closes

Tags: reactjs, browser, tabs, logout

I'm storing session information in **`sessionStorage`**. Currently, when a user opens the application and if **`sessionStorage`** is null, the session logs out. However, I want the session to log out automatically when the browser or tab is closed, but not when the user navigates to other links.

To summarize, I want to disable the jwt that we keep in the backend by sending a request to the logout endpoint when the tab is closed.

I tried with "beforeunload" function but it doesnt work for me